# Python place in frames

Tags: python, tkinter, frames

I have been trying to create a 'dice simulator' using Tkinter in python, but when i try to poisition my 'Text' widget inside its Frame, it stays fixed in the top left of the frame. I have tried the grid, move, and place functions but none work. Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from random import *
def roll():
    txt.delete(0.0, END)
    txt.insert(END, str(randint(1,6)))
window = Tk()
window.title('Dice simulator')
canvas = Canvas(window, width=800, height=500, bg='brown')
canvas.pack()
dice = canvas.create_rectangle(375, 225, 425, 275, fill='white')
frame = Frame(canvas, width=25, height=15)
window = canvas.create_window(400, 295, window=frame)
txtframe = Frame(canvas, width=50, height=50)
txtwindow = canvas.create_window(400, 250, window=txtframe, width=49, height=49)
txt = Text(txtframe, font=50)                                                                                                                                         
button = Button(frame, text='Roll', command=roll)
button.pack()
txt.pack()
```

What are your suggestions? Help will be appreciated.

Details given above, not amazing at this website. Just started.

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what are you trying to achieve. Can you show expected output?

Comment: Typo error  `txt = Text(txtframe, font=50)++` should be `txt = Text(txtframe, font=50`)

Comment: Thanks, i know, and thanks for feedback! I changed the code anyway but basically the text will appear in the top-left hand corner of the frame, i want it to appear centred. I will upload a pic in a sec

Comment: Sorry, I don't have enough 'reputation' to show you an image.

Comment: The important question is where do you *want* the text to be? Have you tried any of the configuration arguments for `pack`? What did you try with `place`? I don't normally advocate using `place`, but you can obviously use it to put widgets wherever you like.

Comment: Your code is working. All I see the Text widget is in center. Did you add window.mainloop()?

Comment: On line 14, you have some hidden canvas behind canvas. Try changing value to 50 to suit your need. `txtwindow = canvas.create_window(400, 50,` This should place on top.

Comment: The text box is in the center.  Do you mean that the number is not in the center of the text box actually?  For your case, use a label instead of text box is better.  Also `window` (initially it is the root window) is overwritten by `window = canvas.create_window(...)`, is it a typo?

Comment: Yes, I did mean that the number is not centred, INSIDE of the text box.

Comment: 'window.mainloop()' shows as an error. Changing value to 50 changes pos.

Answer (score 0):

Centering content in a frame can be done with the pack parameters `expand` and `fill`:

```
widget.pack(expand=True, fill='both')
```

To keep the frame from adjusting its size to the contents you can use the `pack_propatage` method.

```
widget.pack_propagate(False)
```

I rewrote your code using a `Label` instead of a `Text` widget, and rearranged it for better readability:

```
from tkinter import *
from random import *

def roll():
    dice_txt.config(text=str(randint(1,6)))

window = Tk()
window.title('Dice simulator')
canvas = Canvas(window, width=800, height=500, bg='brown')
canvas.pack()

# Dice
dice = canvas.create_rectangle(375, 225, 425, 275, fill='white')
txtframe = Frame(canvas, width=50, height=50)
# Keep txtframe from changing size when dice_txt does
txtframe.pack_propagate(False)
dice_txt = Label(txtframe, font=50)
# Put the dice_text in te center of txtframe
dice_txt.pack(expand=True, fill='both')
txtwindow = canvas.create_window(400, 250, window=txtframe, width=49, height=49)

# Roll button
frame = Frame(canvas, width=25, height=15)
window = canvas.create_window(400, 295, window=frame)
button = Button(frame, text='Roll', command=roll)
button.pack()
```

Comment: What about this one ? change the value to 50...`txtwindow = canvas.create_window(400, 50, ....)`. So you can see all three widgets.

Comment: No, go with @acw1668 suggestion instead. Much better solution.

Answer (score 0):

For your simple dice simulator, you don't need those frame and text widgets, just use `.create_text()` to show the generated dice number instead:

```py
import random
import tkinter as tk

def roll():
    canvas.itemconfig(dice, text=random.randint(1, 6))

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Dice Simulator")
canvas = tk.Canvas(window, width=800, height=500, bg="brown")
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_rectangle(375, 225, 425, 275, fill="white")
dice = canvas.create_text(400, 250, font=('', 40))
button = tk.Button(canvas, text="Roll", width=5, command=roll)
canvas.create_window(400, 295, window=button)
window.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image]